# Word for out of main expertise

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose that a user uses a search engine for searching. It is expected that his searches are mostly about his main expertise/interests. However he may sometimes search other things that accidentally catch his attention. Is there any word for those searches? Some candidates may be:

1. Out-of-expertise searches
2. Out-of-interest searches
3. Out-of-focus searches

Comment: 'Peripheral' means 'not central, not focusing on the central issues [as defined by normal practice]'. 'Dilettante' in the relevant sense means 'just dabbling in this'.

Comment: For the accidental aspect of such searches, consider "occasional" or "incidental". But, these words may also refer to unusual searches done within areas of expertise.

Comment: In fact, I preferred "occasional" the most among answers, Is there any opposition to that?

Answer (score 1):

How about *off-topic* searches? An *off-topic* search is one that lies outside one's main focus/area of expertise/interests.

Another possibility is *side-track* searches. One could easily be *sidetracked* from one's main objective by an alluring find.

And yet another possibility is *tangent searches*. One could easily go off on an unintended *tangent* unrelated to one's main focus/area of expertise/interests.

Answer (score 1):

The searches you did on things you stumbled upon during searches of your main interests are perhaps ***incidental*** searches. They are chance occurrences and a minor result of your actual searches.

M-W:

> **[incidental](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incidental)**
> *adjective*
>
> **1 a** :  being likely to ensue as a chance or minor consequence : social
> obligations incidental to the job
>
> **b** :  minor
>
> **2** :  occurring merely
> by chance or without intention or calculation
>
> You may incur some incidental expenses on the trip.
>
> an incidental part of the job

Answer (score 0):

Yes, may I suggest that the OP's examples might be consolidated and served by the word **extraneous**.

Let me give an example of the word-in-context:

The professor explained to his downcast student that he might have garnered a better grade if his written paper had been less **extraneous** and more like a text-book answer to the assignment's question.

**Extraneous:** (adjective) Not forming a necessary part of something; not forming an essential or vital part; having no relevance. (M-W)

Comment: @Silenus Good comment. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

*Secondary interest searches*

Once you've said that a few times in your article, or whatever you're writing, you can abbreviate this to

*secondary searches*

Answer (score 0):

You may call them ***casual*** searches.

M-W:

> **[casual](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/casual)**
>   *adjective*
>
> : happening by chance : not planned or expected
>
> : done without much thought, effort, or concern
>
> a casual encounter on the sidewalk

Answer (score 0):

If the search were both accidental and fortuitous, then one could call the search [Serendipitous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/serendipitous).